# Using a checkbox to delete an object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got the following form:

```
<%= form_for(@subscription = @task.subscriptions.build(:user_id => subscribers.id)) do |f| %>   
    <%= f.check_box :subscribed, :class => 'submittable' %>
    <%= f.label :subscribed, subscribers.full_name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => subscribers.id %> 
    <%= f.hidden_field :task_id, :value => @task.id %>
<% end %>
```

The 'submittable' class on the checkbox causes the form to be submitted (via jQuery) on update.

:susbcribed is returned via a method in model that returns whether a user is subscribed or not - it cannot be modified directly.

The controller is available here: http://pastebin.com/zZy6KcXz - it is the standard scaffold.

When I click the checkbox, the subcription is successfully created, but I cannot work out how to get it to delete the subscription when unticked.

Comment: It helps if you post your controller code as well.

Comment: Sorry I should have said, the controller is presently the standard scaffold.

Comment: I've added it here for extra info http://pastebin.com/zZy6KcXz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cjm, in follow up to jimworm's answer, the controller's `destroy` method is called when you DELETE (HTTP verb, it's actually a `POST` with a `_method=DELETE` field passed since some browsers don't support the `DELETE` verb.

as he said:

`<%= link_to 'Delete', @model, :confirm=> 'Are you sure?', :method=> :delete %>`

The route is the same as your `show` or `GET /models/1` but the verb `DELETE` is used instead,

`DELETE /models/1`

which is actually

`POST /models/1` with a hidden field `_method=DELETE` passed in order to support all browsers.

As he also mentioned, Rails automatically figures out which action to use when using `form_for` by checking to see if the `@model` is a `new_record?` (no `id` yet) or an existing one.  It will then pick

`POST /models` for `create`

or

`PUT /models/1` for `update`

Comment: can I just check, would 'Delete' call the delete method or the destroy method?

Comment: `:method => :delete` is talking about the HTTP verb `DELETE`. In rails terms, it's called `destroy` (since you destroy `ActiveRecord`s i think?). As a result, `DELETE /resource/id` will call the `destroy` method on the controller. A little confusing, I know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `form_for @subscription`, so it'll probably be submitting to the `create` or `update` actions, which don't destroy models. You could hack the action or the model to make it destroy on create(!)/update. Probably the action... updating the model for this hack gives me the heeby-jeebies.

The Rails way™ to the `DELETE` method and get to the destroy route is a link like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @model, :confirm=> 'Are you sure?', :method=> :delete %>
```

Watch out for IE9 though. If you let your redirects go to another "deleteable" it'll potentially go up the chain and delete your entire database. http://techno-weenie.net/2011/8/19/ie9-deletes-stuff/

The correct redirect after successful `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` is:

```
redirect_to path, :status => 303
```

Comment: Oh my bad, it's probably `create`. It's how `form_for` works. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: Sorry- that isn't clear- how do you know it is submitting the update or create action, and in what circumstances?

Comment: Ah. Rails knows if it's a `POST` request (the default) or a `PUT` (which `form_for` adds if `model.new_record? == false`).

Comment: So does a DELETE request result in a destroy? It said no route 'delete' found when I tried this.

Comment: `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` are HTTP methods, not separate URIs. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods However you can see their routes when you run `rake routes`.